# Decrypting file stored in AWS S3 by Kinesis firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kms

I'm using Kinesis firehose to stream log data from Cloudwatch to AWS S3. The files are encrypted by kinesis data delivery stream with sse kms then stored in S3. However files are greater than 4kb, so i assume kinesis is using envelope encryption with a data key;
After this, i downloaded the data form s3 with:
`aws s3api get-object` or `aws s3 cp` and tried to decrypt it with: \

```
aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://encryptedData --output text
--query Plaintext | base64 --decode > ExamplePlaintextFile
```

and got the error:

> An error occurred (413) when calling the Decrypt operation: HTTP
> content length exceeded 200000 bytes.

When looking to Cloudtrail I can see the `GenerateDataKey` made by Kinesis. The question is where is that data key and how can i got my file decrypted. Did anyone faced this ? 
Thank you !

Comment: cloudwatch logs sends gzip [compressed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-cloudwatch-logs.html) data to firehose. so decompress the file delivered to s3 bucket first before opening it. Firehose wont add .gz extension in this case

Comment: I de-activated encryption to actually check if the problem has something to do with KMS. I still get binary format in the files stored in s3 by firehose (like <8a>^M´Bü{74<ª¶òaG³»3ÚñA¬)<84..."). When i do some get record on the kinesis stream i have base64 encoded log entries which are good. So the problem might be on the process of ingestion from kinesis data stream to firehose

Comment: most likely the issue is not with encryption. it is with gzip compressed data that cloudwatch sends to firehose when you create subscription filter. If you do not have any lambda data transformation function for decompressing these records then firehose sends those records as it is in compressed format to destination. You need to decompress this file before opening it in order to get actual data

Comment: Thank you, the data was in level 6 gzip encryption format. A zcat did the trick.